# Is there a list on when you should do the driving in LA Noire?

Tags: la-noire

In some sequences of the game, if you drive yourself you will catch the suspect in the act of doing something and net more evidence. For example in 'The Driver's Seat' if you drive to the suspect's house you can catch him by surprise before he escapes. Is there a list somewhere of when I should drive to a destination without spoiling the game for me?

Comment: Are you sure that only happens if you drive during that case?

Comment: yes, if I tell my partner to drive he climbs out of the window. Also, I noticed I got the wrong case...whoops!

Comment: Interesting. I never drove in that game. Apart from when it forces you to.